# How to make pinia store state available to all vue.js 3 components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state-management, pinia

i want to fetch user data from pinia so i created this file : **UseUserStore.js**

```
// UseUserStore.js

import axios from '@axios'

import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
export const useUserStore = defineStore('UserData', {

  state: () => ({
    loggedUser: null,
  }),
  actions: {
    async fetchUser() {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/axios/getUserData', {
      })

      this.loggedUser = data.user
    },
  },

})
```

and my **main.js** is :

```
import App from '@/App.vue'
import i18n from '@/plugins/i18n'
import router from '@/router'
import { mapStores , createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { useUserStore } from '@store/useUserStore';

loadFonts()

// Create vue app
const app = createApp(App)

// Use plugins
app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)
app.use(abilitiesPlugin, ability, {
  useGlobalProperties: true,
})

// i tried this but dosent work

// Mount vue app
app.mount('#app')
```

i want to use the loggedUser from all components without importing it and fetchUser everytime.

Comment: For auto import: https://github.com/unplugin/unplugin-auto-import